# DB gratuito para distribuição juntamente com aplicação comercial

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, licença

Vinha andando lendo determinadas licenças de alguns softwares SGBD juntamente com o próprio BD e surgiu uma dúvida muito confusa.

O MariaDB (Versão gratuita) ele é open-source, mas eu poderia distribuir ele, junto com minha aplicação comercialmente? Estou falando do seguinte caso:

1 - Minha aplicação ela não inclui o MariaDB dentro juntamente com o código, ela apenas faz a conexão com um plugin com licença LGPL, que no caso seria o do Java disponível no próprio site do MariaDB.

Por exemplo, um arquivo é minha aplicação e o outro o instalador do banco separadamente.

Comment: Não entendi. É uma pergunta ou uma afirmação? Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Pergunta Retificada.

Answer (score 0):

Com a LGPL você pode distribuir com códigos proprietários. Você só não pode fazer trabalhos derivados sem abrir o código.

http://www.cce.ufpr.br/pds-ufpr/ProcessoDemoisellePlugin/guidances/supportingmaterials/tiposLicencasSoftware_AD711F8B.html

Comment: Então no caso, eu poderia distribuir, minha aplicação + plugin LGPL de conexão (juntos) + o instalador do banco separado?

Comment: Sim,  se o plugin é lgpl eu tenho certeza absoluta. Sobre o banco, se ele é freeware ou aberto, também